# Как mutex определяет, какой именно объект нужно блокировать?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, mutex

Как известно,

> Задача мьютекса — защита объекта от доступа к нему других потоков,
>   отличных от того, который завладел мьютексом. В каждый конкретный
>   момент только один поток может владеть объектом, защищённым мьютексом.
>   Если другому потоку будет нужен доступ к переменной, защищённой
>   мьютексом, то этот поток блокируется до тех пор, пока мьютекс не будет
>   освобождён.

Но как мьютекс определяет, доступ к какому именно ресурсу/объекту/переменной нужно блокировать? Ведь в него не передается никаких параметров, из которых он мог бы знать что именно защищать.

Если что, речь о `std::mutex`, *с++11*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Дополню ответ @alexis031182.

Мьютекс или семафор, как его обобщение (конкретно, объект (переменная), расположенный по некоторому адресу) это точка синхронизации потоков кода одного или (в некоторых случаях) нескольких процессов.

И ничего более. Он ничего не защищает. Ни объекты в памяти, ни участки кода. Поток не вызывающий операцию `lock` с этим мьютексом может делать что хочет с любыми переменными и участками кода. Защита производится на логическом уровне (в голове разработчика).

Фактически  поток кода, вызвавший операцию `lock` для указанного мьютекса увеличивает счетчик, связанный с этим мьютексом и продолжает выполнение если счетчик был равен нулю.

В противном случае этот поток  ожидает, пока счетчик не станет равен 0 (тогда он в свою очередь увеличит его и продолжит выполняться), что произойдет, когда кто-то вызовет `unlock`, уменьшающий счетчик на 1.

Answer (score 10):

У любого мютекса есть функции lock и unlock (они могут называться по разному, но суть от этого не меняется. Некоторые мютексы могут использовать raii, автоматически вызывая нужные функции).

А защищает он кусок кода, который не может быть исполнен, если мютекс в залоченном состоянии. То есть, один мютекс может защищать много различных мест и они не будут исполнены одновременно (актуально при многопоточном выполнении). С другой стороны, в системе может существовать много мютексов одновременно и они не будут мешать друг-дружке.

Comment: `не будут мешать друг-дружке` ... пока в один прекрасный момент не возникает *dead-lock* :)

Comment: Это только в том случае, если кто то попытается блокировать их в произвольном режиме. Сортировка решает частично эту проблему.

Answer (score 9):

По сути, никак. Он и не защищает конкретный объект.

Мьютекс лишь гарантирует, что обращения к данным под мьютексом сериализованы. (То есть, что невозможны гонки данных.) Ответственность работать с нужными объектами возлагается на вас, программиста.

То, что вы описали, говорит не о том, что *делает* мьютекс, а лишь о том, для чего он предназначен, и что вы *можете* при помощи него делать (сами).

Comment: "гонки данных" = "race condition" ?

Comment: @Kromster: Угу, но именно data race. Потому что ещё могут быть другие race'ы.

Comment: @VladD you can win the race!

Answer (score 7):

Мьютекс по сути обеспечивает то, что называется «критической секцией» (критическим разделом) - т.е. код, который может выполняться одновременно только одним потоком.

Но если данный мьютекс навесить на код, который обращается к некоторой переменной - то создается впечатление, что он защищает объект, а не фрагмент кода.

Comment: поправил на более распространённый вариант именования в русском языке.

Comment: @ixSci Забавно, где именно более распространено? Поиск в Гугле "критическая секция C++"  дает 3480 результатов, а раздел - 45800. Как бы выразиться... Тут, простите за каламбур, некритично, но в русскоязычной литературе все же принят именно критический раздел кода...

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, не осталось технических книг на русском, поэтому показать где конкретно, я не могу. В качестве примера, могу привести [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=critical%20section&langID=ru-ru) и тот факт, что я впервые слышу словосочетание «критический раздел», по отношению к critical section понятию из программирования, а у меня высшее профильное образование.

Comment: Да и [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Критическая_секция) тоже за мой вариант. В общем, как я и говорил — в русском языке есть принятое наименование «critical section» — «критическая секция».

Comment: Ну, что под рукой нашел - "Язык программирования Go" Кернигана и Донована, "Эффективный и современный С++" Мейерса, "Стандартная библиотека C++" Джосаттиса - везде раздел. Спорить не хочу, просто поясняю, что ли, почему я пишу именно "раздел".

Comment: В Интернете - и IBM Knowledge Center, и MSDN пишут "раздел"...

Comment: Я же Вам ссылку дал на официальную позицию МС по переводу, где в MSDN Вы нашли другое?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/ru-RU?query=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4  И еще раз - наша дискуссия все равно не изменит терминологию, используемую не нами :), так что спорить смысла никакого.

Comment: Кстати, посмотрите по вашей ссылке ниже - ребята из MS не слишком заморачиваются своими же переводами, и благополучно используют "раздел". На ТОЙ ЖЕ странице :)

Comment: Да, я видел, но там больше не к программированию применяется «раздел». За это, кстати, не люблю переводы — переводчики никакие. Терминологией очень часто вообще не владеют. Правда, в их оправдание можно сказать, что никакого реестра терминологии нет и иногда приходится выдумывать. p.s в ABBYY Lingvo тоже мой вариант.

Comment: Про переводчиков звучит забавно - в том смысле, что откуда-то вы же взяли секцию? Явно же из какого-то перевода? :) Так что тут не столько правильная терминология, сколько "кто первый встал - того и тапки". И переводится часто, что называется, фонетически - как в случае с секцией (типа, чего мучиться? section - явная ж секция :)). А что до качества переводов... Слышал о том, что при переводе на русский "Компиляторов" Ахо-Ульмана-Сети-Рави было исправлено более 120, что ли, ошибок (не опечаток типа hte->the, а именно ошибок).

Answer (score 3):

Позвольте аллегорию... Кто раньше встал, того и тапки. Нет никакой необходимости отмечать сей факт на них самих. Первый надел - владей, ты победил. Соответственно, кто не успел, тот опоздал, и будет пребывать в унылом ожидании, пока столь полезный, но совершенно неразделяемый ресурс не будет освобождён. Конечно, в какой-то мере пример притянут за уши, поскольку в реальной жизни нельзя исключить вариант силового решения вопроса. Но речь о мьютексах, а потому безусловность контроля за процессом передела имущества само собой разумеется. Лишь добрая воля счастливчика, на этот раз успевшего первым, позволит другому воспользоваться предметом вожделенного комфорта.

Сам себя дополню.

С тапками аллегория не получилось потому, что многие могут представить себе рабочее существование без них. А суть не в тапках, а в контексте выполнения. Посредством мьютекса контекст выполнения одного потока блокирует/высвобождает контекст выполнения другого или других. А так - да, тапки ни при чём, дело в голове.

> — Кстати, д’Артаньян: я слышал, что некий Милон Кротонский проделывал
> удивительные вещи. Он, например, обматывал голову верёвкой и одним
> движением головных мускулов!!!… разрывал её. Он сбивал быка одним
> ударом кулака и уносил его на своих плечах… ну, и тому подобное. Я,
> когда узнал обо всём этом… Я проделал у себя в Пьерфоне… ну, всё то же
> самое, что и этот Милон. За исключением одного: я никак не мог
> разорвать головой верёвку.
>
> — Это оттого, что у Вас сила… не в голове.